# Autoincrement column unless specified

Tags: sql, constraints, ddl, unique-constraint

I want to create a table in which there is an attribute named `HashTag`. I want that whenever my insert query has a value for this field then that value should be used but if no value for HashTag is specified in the insert query then any *random* and *unique* value should be automatically assigned. 
Can I specify that in SQL definition?

Comment: To check the value and decide what to do, you need a TRIGGER for BEFORE INSERT. Most RDBMS support this. As to the random part... that depends on what the RDBMS you are using has to offer. You should edit your question and add info on what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can do such thing in SQL. I'll recommend using identity instead.